# How to create HTML Slides with audio for online lectures?

Tags: teaching, presentation

This follows on from a recent question about [embedding audio in PDF slides](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2862/how-to-create-pdf-of-slides-with-audio). I don't like the thought of users needing to use a particular PDF viewer in order to hear the audio and I don't like the thought of needing proprietary software just to create the presentations. Thus, another option would be to create HTML slides. There are a range of HTML slide production approaches (e.g., [S5](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/s5/), [DZSlides](http://paulrouget.com/dzslides/), [Slidy](http://www.w3.org/Talks/Tools/Slidy/), [Slideous](http://goessner.net/articles/slideous/)).

**Update**: 
I was thinking about  using [pandoc to convert markdown into one of the slide formats](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#producing-slide-shows-with-pandoc). @Federico mentions the audio HTML tag. I assume that would be part of an overall solution. This presumably represents a basic answer, but I'd be keen to get some guidance about how this works on a practical level:

- **Are there any examples of implementing audio in HTML slides?**
- **Are there any strategies for increasing the usability of consuming and activating the audio?**
- **Are there any browser or operating system compatibility issues?**

Thus, in a broad sense my question is

**How can HTML slides be created in an effective and efficient way with embedded audio?**

Comment: I've posted this question to the [webapps chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5802247#5802247), maybe someone there will have some insight.

Answer (score 6):

If I read correctly, in all those HTML slide systems you write the HTML file directly, it is not produced by some external tool. So I think you can simply put an [audio tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp) in it. Or am I missing something?

Comment: +1 Thanks for that. I've update the question to try to highlight that my question concerns some of the broader workflow and usability issues related to creating such slides.

Answer (score 3):

A different option would be creating a [screencast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screencast). A screencasting program would record your slides as they play as well as recording voice (or other sounds) from the microphone. [Jing](http://www.techsmith.com/jing.html) is a free, though limited, screencast program. [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) is another free program. There programs you can purchase that include advanced features, including editing and post-production.

The benefit of this method is that your lecture is now a video file, which rarely requires any type of special software, and you can share them easily on youtube, vimeo, or social media.

Comment: I like the idea of a self-contained file. Hopefully any system would minimise the video file size given that the visual information on slides rarely changes. There would be pros and cons. Slide approaches allow you to create audio one slide at a time. Thus, if you make errors, you only need to redo audio for the slide. Slides also create a convenient navigational system for students/listeners.